# How to dynamically create a polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to create a `paper-toast` element with javascript using

```
var toast = document.createElement('paper-toast');
```

That successfully creates the element and I then add it to the body after setting some attributes.

```
document.body.appendChild(toast);
```

This also works, the element shows up in DevTools. But then, when I try to call

```
toast.show();
```

even when deferred (using setTimeout(1)) it errors with undefined is not a function, due to the newly created element not having the function properties that it should according to the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-toast.html).

How can I now use the show method of the element? It does not have to be created dynamically, I only need to be able to change the content fully and this seemed like an easy solution.

Comment: Are you importing the element's definition? You can create any arbitrary element, but it's not going to have special methods until it gets upgraded. If you can create a more comprehensive example, it will be easier to help. Otherwise, I will just be guessing at a solution.

Comment: Aha! Glad I could help. I posted an answer with a handy bookmarklet you can use to detect missing imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to import the element definition with an html import.

```
<link rel="import" href="components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
```

When you have a lot of custom elements, it can be hard to tell which ones are missing imports. You can use the this bookmarklet to detect missing imports

https://gist.github.com/ebidel/cea24a0c4fdcda8f8af2

```
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20isUnregisteredCustomElement(el)%7Bif(el.constructor==HTMLElement)%7Bconsole.error('Found%20unregistered%20custom%20element:',el);return%20true;%7Dreturn%20false;%7Dfunction%20isCustomEl(el)%7Breturn%20el.localName.indexOf('-')!=-1%7C%7Cel.getAttribute('is');%7Dvar%20allCustomElements=document.querySelectorAll('html%20/deep/%20*');allCustomElements=Array.prototype.slice.call(allCustomElements).filter(function(el)%7Breturn%20isCustomEl(el);%7D);var%20foundSome=false;for(var%20i=0,el;el=allCustomElements[i];++i)%7Bif(isUnregisteredCustomElement(el))%7BfoundSome=true;%7D%7Dif(foundSome)%7Balert('Oops:%20found%20one%20or%20more%20unregistered%20custom%20elements%20in%20use!%20Check%20the%20console.');%7Delse%7Balert('Good:%20All%20custom%20elements%20are%20registered%20:)');%7D%7D)();
```